# static class initialization with static references

Tags: c#, static

In the following code, why `Library.genres[n].booklist` are null at runtime for all items in `Library.genres`? Just like if the definitions for `dramabooks` and `kidsbooks` were not being considered for the static initialization:

```
static class Library
{
   public static List<Genre> genres = new List<Genre>()
   {
      new Genre("Drama", dramabooks),
      new Genre("Kids", kidsbooks)
   };

   public static List<Book> dramabooks = new List<Book>() {
      new Book("book1"), 
      new Book("book2")
   };

   public static List<Book> kidsbooks = new List<Book>(){
      new Book("book3"),
      new Book("book4")
   };
}

class Genre
{
   string catname;
   List<Book> booklist;

   Genre(string catname, List<Book> booklist)
   {
      this.catname = catname;
      this.booklist = booklist;
   }
}

class Book
{
   string title;

   Book(string title)
   {
      this.title = title;
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints on all your initialization code to see the order of initialization? @jonskeet has a good blog post on the finer (/weirder) rules involved in static initialization

Comment: this is because Genre is instance. first thing you have just declare static members dramabooks and kidsbooks. you want initialize them then you need to use constructor of Library class. I mean you initialize from static constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding any other code errors (and there are many), This is due to how *static fields* initialise, which is in the textual order of which they appear. `kidsbooks` and `dramabooks` haven't been initialised when `genres` initialises

From the [ECMA C# Specifications](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf)

> **15.5.6.2 Static field initialization**
>
> **The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
> sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in
> which they appear in the class declaration** (§15.5.6.1). Within a
> partial class, the meaning of "textual order" is specified by
> §15.5.6.1. If a static constructor (§15.12) exists in the class,
> execution of the static field initializers occurs immediately prior to
> executing that static constructor. Otherwise, the static field
> initializers are executed at an implementation-dependent time prior to
> the first use of a static field of that class.

In short, use a static constructor where you can express the order of initialisation explicitly, it's less prone to error and more declarative

```
static class Library
{
   static Library()
   {

      dramabooks = new List<Book>()
      {
         new Book("book1"),
         new Book("book1")
      };

      kidsbooks = new List<Book>()
      {
         new Book("book3"),
         new Book("book4")
      };
      genres = new List<Genre>()
      {
         new Genre("Drama", dramabooks),
         new Genre("Kids", kidsbooks)
      };

   }

   public static List<Genre> genres;

   public static List<Book> dramabooks;

   public static List<Book> kidsbooks;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer. I added the `new Book` constructor which I missed when writing the post, just for completeness of the post, and so that other people find it useful after your answer.